# Using only one antibody to detect COX-2 enzyme

Tags: antibody, western-blot

If I wanted to detect COX-2 from a western blot test, would only a primary antibody work? I'm on a budget so does anyone know of relatively cheap COX-2 antibodies?

Comment: Considering that you would need to conjugate the primary antibody to HRP or fluorophores (depending on what detection method you're using), it may well be cheaper to use a secondary antibody.

Comment: Unfortunately, you'll often find a relationship between cost and quality in antibodies. Sure, there's lots of cheap Abs on the market, but is it really worth saving $50 on the Ab if you have to repeat your western 6 or 8 times to get an image-quality result? I used to do tech support for a reagent company, and I've heard *lots* of stories....